# Find the remote VPN address of the network to which I am connected

Tags: windows-7, networking, vpn, internet, ip-address

I am getting Internet from a Huawei 3G data card in Windows 7. I just read about being anonymous on the Internet so thought I'd give it a try. I used [PD Proxy](http://www.pdproxy.com/index.htm) for that, using a username and password, which I got after signing up on their website.

PD Proxy is a software in which I just put a username and password, click on connect and after some seconds it gets connected. So I am unable to know where (remote address) it gets connected to.

If I knew the remote address I could use it using with NMD VPN or OpenVPN with an `.ovpn` configuration file.

So what is the server address of the network to which I am connected (after PD Proxy gets connected)?

I can see the a DNS server address and IP address of my computer using `ipconfig`. Is the DNS server is the server address of the VPN network to which I am connected?

Comment: Not necessarily. I think you need to read about what DNS is, what gateways are, what NAT is and how they work to allow internetworking. What do you mean by what is the server address you are connected to? The VPN server device gives you an address (usually by DHCP) and it has its own gateway to route your network requests to the VPN or Internet, this is "a" method of anonymity as the VPN server's Internet connection gets the page you've requested, not your ISP's DNS servers.

Comment: @BigChris yes thanks. I will go through that but for now Please tell how can I find remote address of VPN Server.

Comment: Look in your VPN connection statistics/ipconfig for the default gateway. You may not get the actual server IP because a VPN server (like any router) can have different addresses. It could be passing the default gateway address of another device that acts as a default gateway. The DNS server addresses might not be the VPN server address (for the same reason). You should really contact the VPN provider.